# How to align columns of unequal contents

Tags: html, css

If contents of one column are more than contents of other columns in a table then by default browser aligns the contents of columns with lesser contents to be `vertical-align: inherit`.

```css
tr {
  page-break-inside: avoid;
}

table,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

span {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>Column 1</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>Column 2</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>This is para 1</p>
      <p>This is para 2</p>
      <p>This is para 3</p>
      <p>This is para 4</p>
      <p>This is para 5</p>
      <p>This is para 6</p>
      <p>This is para 7</p>
      <p>This is para 8</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But in my case I want them to be `vertical-align: top`. Setting this results in pulling the contents of columns with lesser contents to start above the contents of columns with more content.

I want to align the content "column 1" and "column 2" content parallel to "This is para 1".

Comment: Can you share your CSS?

Comment: @oram I have added the css in head section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that in addition to `vertical-align: top;` for the `td` tag you need to change the default CSS of the `p` tag.
Once you remove the `margin-top` the text will go to the top of the cell.

I added these changes:

```
td {
  vertical-align: top;
}

p {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

See snippet below:

```css
tr {
  page-break-inside: avoid;
}

table,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td {
  vertical-align: top;
}

span {
  margin: 10px;
}

p {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>Column 1</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>Column 2</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>This is para 1</p>
      <p>This is para 2</p>
      <p>This is para 3</p>
      <p>This is para 4</p>
      <p>This is para 5</p>
      <p>This is para 6</p>
      <p>This is para 7</p>
      <p>This is para 8</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Alternatively, you can put the text of the other cells inside a `p` tag instead of a `span` tag which will cause them to have the same styling and get the same `margin-top` value and `display: block;`.

```css
tr {
  page-break-inside: avoid;
}

table,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>Column 1</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>Column 2</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>This is para 1</p>
      <p>This is para 2</p>
      <p>This is para 3</p>
      <p>This is para 4</p>
      <p>This is para 5</p>
      <p>This is para 6</p>
      <p>This is para 7</p>
      <p>This is para 8</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `valign` attribute to your `td valign="top"` for smaller content. Optionally to make it center and bottom aligned content use `valign-center` and `valign-bottom`as follow.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        tr {
            page-break-inside: avoid;
        }
        
        table,
        td,
        th {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
        
        span {
            margin: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>3</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <p>Column 1</p>
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
                <p>Column 2</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>This is para 1</p>
                <p>This is para 2</p>
                <p>This is para 3</p>
                <p>This is para 4</p>
                <p>This is para 5</p>
                <p>This is para 6</p>
                <p>This is para 7</p>
                <p>This is para 8</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: notice the contents are above the "This is para 1" text

Comment: I have updated the snippet. If you use `p` tag instead `span` the become same line.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```css
tr {
  page-break-inside: avoid;
}

table,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Column 1
      </td>
      <td>
       Column 2
      </td>
      <td>
        This is para 1<br>
        This is para 2<br>
        This is para 3<br>
        This is para 4<br>
        This is para 5<br>
        This is para 6<br>
        This is para 7<br>
        This is para 8<br>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

it obvious you need to use align property to adjust your text.

And try use `<br>` instead of `<p>` in the table.

**But** if u still insist to use `<p>` tag,

then you also need to apply `<p>` tag for the first and second column instead of `<span>`. 
it is because `<p>`  and `<span>` is not the same div. so your text won't align with each other.

Answer (score -1):

Use `valign` like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top">
      <span>Column 1</span>
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
      <span>Column 2</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>This is para 1</p>
      <p>This is para 2</p>
      <p>This is para 3</p>
      <p>This is para 4</p>
      <p>This is para 5</p>
      <p>This is para 6</p>
      <p>This is para 7</p>
      <p>This is para 8</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```